# Tuning of Server Thread pool

Tags: multithreading, server, tomcat8

I was just playing with threads and see how much CPU they consume. I have checked in two scenarios.

- In first scenario I created four threads and started them with  infinite loop.  Soon those threads consumed my all 4 CPU cores. After checking performance monitor in task manager I found CPU consumption is 100%.
- In second scenario when I tried it with web application and in rest controller(using tomcat server 8.5 version) I have run infinite loop. So that if I request url 4 times with browser(with different tabs obviously). My CPU consumption should be 100%. I couldn't see 100% CPU consumption.

Why is there difference?

My Second question is: how would I tune the server thread pool. I have to use more than 4 threads because it might be possible few of them are waiting for IO operation. I am using hibernate as ORM that maintains connection pooling. So how many threads I should use in thread pool as well as connection pool. How would I decide?

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer the first part of your question without seeing your code.  But I suspect the problem is in the way that you have implemented the threads in the webapp case.  (Because what you report shouldn't happen ...)

The answer to the second part is "trial and error".  More specifically:

1. Make the pool sizes tunable parameters
2. Develop a benchmark that is representative of your expected system load.
3. Run benchmark with different settings, measure performance and graph results.
4. Based on the graph (and other criteria) pick a settings that are the best compromise between performance and resource (e.g. memory) utilization.

Thread pools and connection pools are different, and have different resource implications.  The first is (largely) about memory; i.e. thread stacks and temporary objects used by the threads while they are active.  The second is (largely) about resources associated with connections (active or idle).